# "Cannot resolve proxy hostname " when installing an application

Tags: software-center, software-installation

I am using 2 screens on my computer and wanted to enable the brightness control on the second monitor. I found an application called "brightness controller" on the software centre but the link provided doesn't work. It is for sale at 0$ and when I click on the buy button, I get an error message.

```
Unable to load page
Problem occurred while loading the URL https://software-center.ubuntu.com/subscriptions/en/ubuntu/precise/+new/?archive_id=commercial-ppa-uploaders%2Fbrightness-controller&arch=i386
Cannot resolve proxy hostname
```

I went to the [application page](https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness), but once there, being a Win XP defector, I do not know what to do with the multiple links provided there.

Comment: You are using a proxy?

Comment: no proxy here..

Comment: Install [firefox export-cookies plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-cookies), go to https://software-center.ubuntu.com and login, run `Tools>Extract Cookies`, save to cookies.txt, then do `wget -S --load-cookies cookies.txt -O - 'https://software-center.ubuntu.com/subscriptions/en/ubuntu/precise/+new/?archive_id=commercial-ppa-uploaders%2Fbrightness-controller&arch=i386'` Paste the output into your question.